# Setting Range Variable based on Multiple Cells' Values

Tags: vba, excel

I have data like this: (I don't know how to post the excel table correctly and for that I apple-o-gize.  I also *really* hope these are not real e-mails)

```
     A               B
1  String     Email
2  Astring1   Aemail@nothingA.xom
3  Astring2   Aemail@nothingA.xom
4  Astring3   Aemail@nothingA.xom
5  Bstring1   Bemail@nothingB.xom
6  Bstring2   Bemail@nothingB.xom
7  Bstring3   Bemail@nothingB.xom
8  Bstring4   Bemail@nothingB.xom
9  Cstring1   Cemail@nothingC.xom
10 Cstring2   Cemail@nothingC.xom
```

I am trying to set a range to variable based on the email field.

i.e.
For the "A's" the below myRng would be A2:A4 and the "B's" would be A5:A8 and so on

```
Set myRng = Range("A1:A" & [the last row where the e-mails are the same])
```

I don't think For...Next or Do loops would work, or at least, I don't know how to make them work.

Any help is greatly appreciated - Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did:

1. Sort columns A:B by email IDS
2. In Column C, create a list of all unique email IDs.
3. Determine the count of each email ID. Use countif:

   ```
   =COUNTIF($B$2:$B$10,C2)
   ```
4. Use match to determine the first cell where the email address appears

   ```
   =MATCH(C2,$B$2:$B$10,0)
   ```
5. Create a range of addresses

   ```
   =ADDRESS(E2,1,4)&":"&ADDRESS(E2+F2-1,1,4)
   ```
6. Create a named range of Column G . Call it "Range_List"

Your excel file would look like this:

```
        A           B                       C               E          F           G
    1   String      Email               Unique Emails       count      Cell start  Range
    2   Astring1    Aemail@nothingA.xom Aemail@nothingA.xom 3          2           A2:A4
    3   Astring2    Aemail@nothingA.xom Bemail@nothingB.xom 4          5           A5:A8
    4   Astring3    Aemail@nothingA.xom Cemail@nothingC.xom 2          9           A9:A10
    5   Bstring1    Bemail@nothingB.xom
    6   Bstring2    Bemail@nothingB.xom
    7   Bstring3    Bemail@nothingB.xom
    8   Bstring4    Bemail@nothingB.xom
    9   Cstring1    Cemail@nothingC.xom
    10  Cstring2    Cemail@nothingC.xom
```

Next step - VBA:

1. Import the excel named range
2. Use a for-loop to go though the named range
3. Get the value of each cell and assign it to myRng
   Example:
   when i=1, the value of the cell is `A2:A4`
   when i=2, the value of the cell is `A5:A8`
   and so on.

```css
Sub Ranges_Macro()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Range_List As Range
    Set Range_List = Sheet1.Range("Range_List")

    For i = 1 To Range_List.Count

        Dim myRng As Range
        Dim Range_String As String
        Range_List.Offset(i - 1, 0).Activate
        Range_String = ActiveCell.Value


        Set myRng = Range(Range_String)

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I just need the countif portion.  i was able to copy/pasta and remove duplicates in the last column.  Is it application.worksheetfunction(countif(.......))?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the unique items in column B then do something with them. Here is a simple example placing the unique items in column C

```
Sub UsingCollection()
    Dim cUnique As Collection
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim vNum As Variant

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set Rng = sh.Range("B2", sh.Range("B2").End(xlDown))
    Set cUnique = New Collection

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
        cUnique.Add Cell.Value, CStr(Cell.Value)
    Next Cell
    On Error GoTo 0

    For Each vNum In cUnique
        Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = vNum
        Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "Do some thing with " & vNum

    Next vNum

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at this tomorrow night